# Custom Registration Form and Passwords

Tags: plugin-development, user-registration

All, I've created a custom registration form on www.safetyworks.com/login.

The problem is the password field. It allows the user to submit the form no problem but the initial password the user puts in does not work. The user has to do a password reset in order for it work. Here is the registration fields code to update the user meta data (which I'm using in a custom plugin):

```
 add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_user_register' );
    function myplugin_user_register( $user_id ) {
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'first_name', trim( $_POST['first_name'] ) );
        }
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['last_name'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'last_name', trim( $_POST['last_name'] ) );
        }
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['job_title'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'job_title', trim( $_POST['job_title'] ) );
        }
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_company'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_company', trim( $_POST['billing_company'] ) );
        }
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['address'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'address', trim( $_POST['address'] ) );
        }
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_city'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', trim( $_POST['billing_city'] ) );
        }
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['state'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'state', trim( $_POST['state'] ) );
        }
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_postcode'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', trim( $_POST['billing_postcode'] ) );
        }
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['phone_number'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'phone_number', trim( $_POST['phone_number'] ) );
        }
        if ( ! empty( $_POST['password'] ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'password', trim( $_POST['password'] ) );
        }
    }
```

What am I missing? Like I said, all other fields seem to be fine.

Comment: Check your db field is same or different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The password is hashed in the DB then you need to set it with `wp_update_user`

```
wp_update_user([
    "ID" => $user_id,
    "user_pass" => $_POST['password'],
]);
```